# How can i update my data in my database using checkbox values?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have this table in my database.

```
id   |  scenario_id |  questions
1         null           test 1
2         null           test 2
3         null           test 3
```

I want to update the `scenario_id` column using the values that I will get on my checkbox.

here is my controller

```
  public function store(Request $request)
    {

      $scenarios = Scenario::create([
           'topic_id' => 1,
           'title' => "Title New Scenario",
           'resources_path' => "Sample",
           'component_type' => $request['scenarios_scenario_component_component'],
           'component' => $request['scenarios_scenario_component_text'],
           'created_by' => Auth::user()->id
      ]);

     $questions= $request->get('scenario_questions'); //my checkbox values

     for ($i=0; $i < count($questions) ; $i++) {
        $questions_update = Question::where('id', $questions[$i])->update([
          'scenario_id', $scenarios->id
        ]);
     }


      return response()->json([
        'success'=>"Success"
      ]);
    }
```

here is my html code:

```
   <input type="checkbox" name="scenario_questions[]" value="92"> Test123
   <input type="checkbox" name="scenario_questions[]" value="91"> What would you do if, let's say for example, a customer starts screaming at you?
   <input type="checkbox" name="scenario_questions[]" value="35"> Today, you will learn how to take in phone calls.
   <input type="checkbox" name="scenario_questions[]" value="34"> I drink coffee before doing anything else. It has become routinary for me.
   <input type="checkbox" name="scenario_questions[]" value="33"> Wait for me at the coffee shop at the back of the office building.
   <input type="checkbox" name="scenario_questions[]" value="32"> In the office, we can wear polos on Mondays. 
   <input type="checkbox" name="scenario_questions[]" value="31"> I had to fall in line for three hours to get these concert tickets.
```

How can I update all of my table columns based on what the user will check on my checkbox? the values of the checkbox is the ID in my table.

I keep having an error of

```
Column not found: 1054 Unknown column '0' in 'field list' (SQL: update `questions` set `0` = scenario_id, `1` = 12, `questions`.`updated_at` = 2020-11-03 10:17:00 where `id` = 92)"
```

Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: In your query you are `updating` the columns wrong, you need to use the table columns names as the names of the `checkboxes` , and you need to add the html code so we can help you!

Comment: hi sir I updated my question and put my html code.

Comment: OH! I ALREADY SAW MY ERROR! ```  $questions_update = Question::where('id', $questions[$i])->update([
          'scenario_id', $scenarios->id
        ]);``` it should be  ``` 'scenario_id' => $scenarios->id```

Comment: I am really sorry for my dumbness! :(. i already fixed it, i shouldve first look my code closely, i am really sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here in your code is wrong

```
for ($i=0; $i < count($questions) ; $i++) {
    $questions_update = Question::where('id', $questions[$i])->update([
      'scenario_id', $scenarios->id
    ]);
 }
```

must be

```
for ($i=0; $i < count($questions) ; $i++) {
    $questions_update = Question::where('id', $questions[$i])->update([
      'scenario_id'=> $scenarios->id
    ]);
 }
```

I think this must work

Comment: yes! this is my fault, i didnt check my code first! sorry sir! thank you sir !

Answer (score 0):

In HTML use `<input type="checkbox" name="check[]" value="cake">`
in controller (using php) do this

```
$checkbox1=$_POST['check'];
```

Now

```
foreach($checkbox1 as $chk1)  
   {  
      $chk .= $chk1.",";  
   }
```